# How to prevent automatic padding by IDA?

Tags: ida

I defined a struct in a header file, similar to this one:

```
struct STRUCT
{
    char a;
    int b;
};
```

This is parsed successfully by IDA, however it adds padding bytes after the `char`:

```
00000000 STRUCT          struc ; (sizeof=0x4)
00000000 a               db ?
00000001                 db ? ; undefined
00000002 b               dw ?
00000004 STRUCT          ends
```

I can't remove the padding field using <kbd>u</kbd>, so the question is: How can one remove padding fields automatically inserted by IDA, or how can one prevent IDA from creating padding fields?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `#pragma pack(1)` before the declaration.

Comment: How can I undo this if I define multiple structs per file? ```#pragma pack(0)```? Does this syntax originate from MSVC?

Comment: `#pragma pack(push, 1)` / `#pragma pack(pop)`

Comment: Worth noting, that if you did wish a member of your struct to be padded, you can define it thus: `__declspec(align(4)) char;`

Answer (score 9):

## removing undefined byte

click on an undefined padding byte, then with `Shrink struct` (right-click menu, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>), choose how many bytes you want to remove - it automatically sets the right amount to the next defined offset.

## preventing auto add

It depends on the parameter in the `Options/Compiler` menu: Change the `default alignment` to 1 to remove padding, then import your header